# SED Command not working in Vagrant Init script

Tags: bash, sed, centos, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a sed command which tailors the httpd.conf file and works perfectly from the command line:

```
sudo sed -i 's/DocumentRoot \"\/var\/www\/html\"/DocumentRoot \"\/var\/www\/html\/web\"/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

However, when included as part of the config.vm.provision in the Vagrant init script it fails as follows:

```
default: sed: 
==> default: couldn't open file ww/html"/DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/web"/: No such file or directory
==> default: sed: -e expression #1, char 44: expected newer version of sed
==> default: sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unknown option to `s'
```

I have tried playing around with the escaping but nothing I try works. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It seems your first `/w` is handled as a write command to `ww\/html\"/DocumentRoot \"\/var\/www\/html\/web\"/` file . That could explain the first error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sed`, you can change the `regex substitution` markers. Here, I am changing `/` to `~` for more clarity of the command.

```
sed -i 's~DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"~DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/web"~' file
```

Comment: thanks for that. Got a similar issue that isn't solved by changing the markers.  `sudo sed -i '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/<\/Directory>/{s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/}' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` gives the same error but changing / to ~ doesn't do the trick. What do I need to do there please?

Comment: @williamsdb, If you have changed `/` to `~`, then you do not need to escape other `/` which appeared on PATH.

Comment: this: `sed: -e expression #1, char 60: expected newer version of sed`

Comment: @williamsdb, what is the version of `sed` ? Use: `sed --version`

Comment: GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: Mine is same too. It should work. Try this : `sed -i.bak '/<Directory "[/]var[/]www[/]html">/,/<[/]Directory>/{s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/}' file`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111656/discussion-between-williamsdb-and-sat).